# Strategies to ensure backend endpoints are being hit by a trusted client?

Tags: javascript, https, webapi

I am building a small web game to practice building a full stack application. The player will play a javascript game in browser, and then their score will be sent to a backend server.

Broadly speaking, are their strategies for confirming scores sent to the backend are from my website alone?

From my understanding, since the game is in browser, the API endpoint for reporting scores must be publicly facing. I cannot think of a way to prevent someone from reporting fake highscores with postman or curl.

If I devised a creative scheme to prevent cheating, wouldn't the user always be able to inspect the javascript sent to them? (And thus, learn how to hack)

Comment: As long as the server doesn't know the state of the client and can calculate the score itself there is nothing you can do against faked highscore requests.